# Boot to Ubuntu installed on USB from Window?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on USB via another boot USB using Rufus, it run smoothly but when I removed USB, all thing waiting for me was Grub Rescue. After I repair Boot loader Window 10 (Bootrec.exe /fixmbr), It could not boot to Ubuntu. I cant access Bios so I cant edit Boot from USB selection, also try EasyBCD but it not works, it same as window, cant recognize Ubuntu installed on USB. Is there any way boot to Ubuntu installed on USB from Window?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? Either way you need boot files on the flash drive. UEFI is a bit more difficult. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

- Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the 'Device' dropdown

  Click the CD Rom icon next to the 'FreeDOS' dropdown, then find your
  downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click 'Open' and then 'Start'

  Click 'Yes' when it asks to download Syslinux software

  Click 'OK' to write in ISO Image mode

  Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then 'OK' to continue

  When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using
  Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu